# How can I secure this sql query from SQL Injection in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, sql-injection

I am trying to create restAPI in Laravel. How can I secure an SQL query like this from sql injection?

```
Route::get('api/restaurant/id/{id}', 'RestaurantController@getRestaurantById');

public function getRestaurantById($id) {
        $restaurant = Restaurant::where('id', $id)->first();

        return $restaurant;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's database query builder provides a convenient, fluent interface to creating and running database queries. It can be used to perform most database operations in your application and works on all supported database systems.

The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings. [introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#introduction)

**Please note that you are not automatically protected if you build raw SQL statements and execute those or use raw expressions.**

Answer (score 5):

If you are using laravel ORM to build your sql queries your queries are automatically protected from sql injections.

For example:

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::where('id', $id)->first();
```

This query is created by laravel ORM and if you run `dd(Restaurant::where('id', $id)->toSql())` you will see that id is not injected in query directly:

```
SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id = ?
```

You can run sql raw queries using `DB::select()` or `DB::raw()` ... e.t.c.
If you look at laravel documentation you will see that every raw methods has array parameter usually second parameter. 
For example:

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id = ?', [$id]);
Restaurant::whereRaw('id = ?', [$id])->first();
...
DB::raw('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id = ?', [$id]);
```

Each of above queries are safe from sql injections.

> Do not write queries like this
>   `DB::select("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id = $id");` This can be extremly dangerous for your app.

For more information look at here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#running-queries

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Laravel Documentation

> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your
>   application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean
>   strings being passed as bindings.

Also

> Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you
>   should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection
>   vulnerabilities.

You should always use parameterized queries when building raw SQL statements or expressions.

[Laravel -> Database: Query Builder -> Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#introduction)

[Laravel -> Database: Query Builder -> Raw Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

If you use eloquent to save and retrieve data from db, you need not worry about sql injections

Answer (score 0):

> Eloquent uses parameter binding behind the scene, which safely escapes
>   any input used in where(). The Laravel query builder uses PDO
>   parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection
>   attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.